# Django project. creat new file

Tags: django

when typing in the command line:>django startproject myfirstproject,
Gives this error: "Django" is not inside or outside
command, executable program, or batch file.
how to fix or what can i do?

I wanted to create a Django project but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the following command.

```
django-admin startproject myfirstproject
```

If this still does not work. Make sure you have correctly installed django in your environment.